# How many hours should I charge this battery?

Tags: electricity

I have a charger and two batteries, the charger has output 250mA with voltage 2.4V, the battery is 1900mAh with voltage 1.2V, how many hours should I charge this battery?

Should I charge 1900*1.2/250/2.4=3.8 hours or should I charge 1900/250=7.6 hours?

The detailed parameters are in the pictures:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your charger designed to charge that battery? What is the battery chemistry? Do you have a data sheet for your battery and/or charger?

Comment: @hekete You ask too many, I think the estimated time can be deduced from the figures I give. I don't need the answer to be very precise.

Comment: The simple formula is T = Ah / A. But there will be losses, so the actual charging time will be longer by quite a bit. Also it isn't necessarily safe for you to charge that batter for x hours with that charger. For example a 1,900mAh battery I would expect to charge at 190mA. Can it be charged at 250mA? I don't know, I know nothing about your battery. It could explode, it could be fine, it could be damaged...

Comment: @hekete You are confused with the battery capacity and charge current, 1900mAh has nothing to do with 190mA.

Comment: I'm not confused. A standard 'safe' rate of charge for a battery is at a rate equal to10% of its capacity. A charger generally applies a constant current to the battery until some voltage is reached. If it applies too much current (or expects too high a voltage to be reached) the battery can be damaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Brief:** Use the charger shown to charge the batteries as per [**This instruction sheet**](https://eneloop101.com/wp-content/uploads/NC-MQN04-EN-small.pdf)
When the charger's LED goes out the batteries are charged.

**Detail:**

The battery is a Sanyo Eneloop HR-3UTGB LSD (Low Self Discharge) Nickel metal hydride cell. These are amongst the best NimH cells available. They have a self discharge shelf life measured in years.

The charger you show part of is a  Sanyo MQN04 charger which will automatically correctly charge either 2 or 4 NimH cells and provide an indication at the end of charging.
[**Sanyo MQN04 charger instructions & specifications here**](https://eneloop101.com/wp-content/uploads/NC-MQN04-EN-small.pdf)

**You do not need to time the charge.**

The charger will determine correct charging requirements.
A full charge on this charger takes about 10 hours.

If you did not have this charger any of the "normal" methods of charging NimH cells can be used.  (These include negative voltage inflection, delta temperature change, absolute temperature, capacity filling)

- Negative voltage inflection: The cell voltage climbs during charging at constant current and then decrease slightly at full charge.   This is the method most commonly used by domestic chargers.
- Delta temperature change: The battery increases in temperature during charging and then suddenly starts getting hot at a much faster rate at the end of charging.
- Absolute temperature: The battery reaches a preset temperature at end of charge. Typically 50 degrees C +
- Capacity filling: From empty tcharge ~= Capacity_mAh/Charge_current_mA x K
  k = 1 to be safe. K=1.1 for closer to full.
  This only applies if the battery is fully discharged.  This is not a good method of charging as it risks charging the battery when it is already full and damaging or destroying it.

An effective less than standard way of charging that you won't find commonly mentioned is to charge it at from 200 to 250 mA until the terminal voltage reaches 1.4 V. This will be close to full capacity.
If charging at lower than 200 mA then the end-of-charge terminal voltage will need to be lower.
Setting too high a terminal voltage for a given cell type and charging rate will lead to charging indefinitely and destroying the battery.

Comment: Unfortunately the charger light won't go off. So I need to estimate the time. From your formula, I need about 8 hours to charge the battery.

Comment: @buzhidao If the charger light does not go off then one or both batteries are faulty OR the charger is faulty OR the batteries are each at different charge levels OR you are using it wrong. Whatever the reason it would be better to find out what was wrong before risking damaging possibly good cells. | My formula is for fully discharged cells (as I noted). You would need to be sure your batteries are both discharged.